# For some vector field, $<P, Q>$, is it possible for $P_{y} = Q_{x}$ and yet not have $\nabla f = <P,Q>$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Even if $P_{y} = Q_{x}$, is it guaranteed that some function exists whose gradient gives $<P,Q>$?

Comment: If you have $P_y = Q_x$, then this implies that $f \in C^2$, the set of functions with continuous second partial derivatives. The reason being that if we assume that $[P,Q] = [f_x,f_y]$ and $P_y = Q_x \implies f_{xy} = f_{yx}$. With the guarantee that second partial derivatives commute, we can definitely form a continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field

$$<P,Q>= \langle -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \rangle $$

satisfies $P_y=Q_x$. However, it is not the gradient of a function defined in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}.$

Answer (score 1):

A closed differential form (or vector field) must be defined and bounded in a star-shaped region for it to be exact. The example user1337 gives fails because it’s undefined at the origin, so the region where it is defined—$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$—isn’t star-shaped.

Comment: Why must it be star shaped?

Comment: In the proof that I have in mind, you construct an antiderivative via line integrals along segments radiating from a chosen point. There may well be different conditions that also make $P_y=Q_x$ sufficient. Note that user1337’s example could still be locally exact in some region that doesn’t include the origin.